# Force TypeScript to show final state of variable on hover

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

In my project it happens in multiple occasion that TypeScript show to me an uninterpreted type.

---

**Example :**

In the following code, hovering over `Foo` will give to me the following result :

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0AU5QuZAbwChkzkZgBnACwC4jTzmE4xLaGqwpQBzANxMyAXwDaAXSEjixMAE8ADigzpkAXkbNI3Bqpx5wYgOQcaxiWIAMU4iKGziQA)

```
interface FooParent {
    fish: {
        catfish: string;
    }[];
}

type Foo = {
    test: FooParent['fish'][0];
};
```

[image]

---

If I want to know about the type of `FooParent['fish'][0]`, I have to interpret it myself.

I saw that it is possible to *trick* TypeScript using the *infer* keywork :

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-beta#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0AU5QuZAbwChkzkZgBnACwC4jTzmE4xLaGqwpQBzANxMyAXwDaAXSEjixMAE8ADigzpkAXkbNI3Bqpx5wYgOQcaxiWIAME5BAAekEABMqyUDGjIAqsgD8RMhiWO4gyADWEPLoMD4SDN7BtiLIDCAQAG7Q0kKyxEA)

---

```
interface FooParent {
    fish: {
        catfish: string;
    }[];
}

type Foo = {
    test: FooParent['fish'][0] extends infer U ? { [P in keyof U]: U[P] } : never;
};
```

[image]

---

But it's unpredictable ([Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.0-beta#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0AU5QuZAbwChkzkZgBnACwC4jTzmE4xLaGqwpQBzANxMyAXwDaAXSEjixMAE8ADigxQkAFSUQAygl6KwAYTgAbBAFcTAHnUA+ZAF5k65BAAekEABMqyUDGhkAFVkAH4iZDEsPxBkAGsIeXQYYIkGIKiJZBFkBhAIADdoITktNExHRmZIbgZVDS1dfSNTC2sMbFx8MDEAcg4aXokxAAYJW2kS2SA)).

---

Do you know of any method allowing TypeScript to show to you the final type of the variable you are hovering on in a simple and reliable way ?

Comment: This is basically the same thing, idk if it's better for your actual use case: https://tsplay.dev/oN9K9W  It still does not evaluate fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your Typescript knowledge, the solution itself could be a bit intense; I provided some comments to walk you through.
But the usage is rather simple and reliable - very analogous to your initial working example: `YourType extends ForceType<infer U> ? U : _whatever_` .

```
interface FooParent {
    fish: {
        catfish: string;
        foo: {
            bar: () => void
        },
        loop: FooParent
    }[];
}

type Foo = {
    test: 
        // FooParent,
        // FooParent extends ForceType<infer U> ? U : never,
        // FooParent['fish'],
        // FooParent['fish'] extends ForceType<infer U> ? U : never,
        // FooParent['fish'][0],
        FooParent['fish'][0] extends ForceType<infer U> ? U : never,
        // FooParent['fish'][0]['catfish'],
        // FooParent['fish'][0]['catfish'] extends ForceType<infer U> ? U : never
    
};

type Index = number | string | symbol
type ForceType<T, Path extends Index[] = Index[]> = Path extends [infer _] ?
 T extends Record<Index, any> ? ForceObject<T, Path>
    : T extends ReadonlyArray<any> ? ForceArray<T, Path>
        : never // neither object nor array; never could only happen if Path was specified explicitly
            : T // closes the first condition - Path is empty we reached a leaf

type ForceObject<T, Path extends Index[]> = Path extends [infer H, ...infer Rest] ?
        Rest extends Index[] ?
            H extends keyof T ? ForceType<T[H], Rest> // traverse and recurse
                : never : never : never // never could only happen if Path was specified explicitly

type ForceArray<T extends ReadonlyArray<any>, Path extends Index[]> = Path extends [number, ...infer Rest] ?
   Rest extends Index[] ? ForceType<T[number], Rest> // traverse and recurse
    : never : never // never could only happen if Path was specified explicitly
```

[PLAYGROUND](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt0AU5QuZAbwChkzkZgBnACwC4jTzmE4xLaGqwpQBzANxNmZGJgYkRU5ACNcDABQBKZAF4AfMgBu6YABNhIgL4AaQ8wA2mAA4MM2XPjCGjAbQC6Qo8WJgAntYo9mqMzJDcDObkAPTRaJg4eOBm0six8Q5JYMgQAB6QIHpU8VBIACoBEAA8oDDQyACqmgD8jcgMIBBa0CnS6faJTq4A5Bw0w+69Uv0JjuAjYxM5+fhFJeWVNSB1UI0tbR1dPVFkM5lDo9Tj7q4ADJMnGYPzl7QTd+7LBWsYpRAVgS2Oz2yFaDXayE63SgUxEZ2eYAWV3e9xGrHYyIeqXhc0Rr2uHzRbEWnzy32Kvw2gNq9SaoIOkKOUEMxCMQl8lWQAElCnkQiAAK4AWxk9QAPshuLwQHxkBKqH4RegLBzAut-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)

The below image was taken with <kbd>CMD</kbd> pressed. Showing the original code and calculated type.

[image: working example from TS playground]

I think ultimately the issue should be addressed on IDE level, as it is mostly a DX challenge. It seems Monaco Editor / VSCode are pretty close to actually address it, but in most cases hovering over a type definition with <kbd>CMD</kbd> pressed displays just duplicated information.

Fortunately, in this case a problem with types can be solved with *even more types*.

Btw. a very nice question - well researched, documented and challenging. Thank you.

Comment: Thank for your answer. It's a good improvement on my actual tricks. Regarding of how to use `ForceType`, I noticed that you have to use it for every attribute of the object, every time you browse an other type, is there a way to only specify it once for all ? Please look at the following describing [playground](https://cutt.ly/jkzkXTR)

Comment: @Orelsanpls I am afraid making it more ergonomic with type only solution might be very hard if not impossible. This explicit `infer U` trick let us unwrap only the top level type. If you really need it I would recommend opening issue in Monaco Editor / VSCode - it feels to me that it should be properly addressed there.